# Attempting to make a WP theme from static HTML; CSS not linking to HTML and can't determine why

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make WP theme out of a static HTML page to help out this non-profit that I'm volunteering for. Coding is not my forte so I am struggling. To learn how to do this, I watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=267&v=CZRgvAtwpxw&feature=emb_logo

To briefly summarize, I chopped the HTML up into a header, index, and footer section, each saved as header.php, etc.

In making the code, the HTML loads without the styling. I suspect the issue is in the header, so I have pasted it here:

````
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>A2Empowerment.org</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="Layer1">
  <p align="center"><a href="index.shtml"><img src="a2e_banner.png" alt="banner" width="650" height="145" border="0" /></a></p>
</div>
</head>```

**The index page is as follows:**

    ```<?php get_header(); ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
<!--#include virtual="title.html"-->

<div id="Layer1">
  <p align="center"><a href="index.shtml"><img src="a2e_banner.png" alt="banner" width="650" height="145" border="0" /></a></p>
</div>...```

**The CSS opens as follows:** 

```/*
Theme Name: Man Ching's Theme.
Theme URI: www.a2empowerment.org
Description: Based on the original static HTML and CSS
Version: 1.0
Author: Dan Araujo
Author URI: none
*/
#Layer1{position:relative;

    top:0%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1;

} ```


Any help on this issue would be fantastic. Everything is saved in the same folder. Thanks!
````

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you shouldn't have that `div` inside your `head`. It should be in your body only. And you shouldn't open another `html` tag after closing the `head`.

You have to check if the CSS is located on the same folder (path) as the current HTML file and being correctly loaded.

1) Open up your browser's developers tools (hit F12 or CTRL+Shift+I) and take a look at the 'Elements' tab. Inspect the 'head' part of the code and click the link to the CSS file (it will start with link href="style.css"...) - if the file doesn't load correctly on your browser and you can't see the CSS, then you'll have to adjust the path to it.

2) If it's already on the correct path, and you know it should be working, then maybe your .htaccess is redirecting all requests (even those to css files) to something else and it will need to be ajusted.

Those are the first things to check. After those are checked and answered we may be able to help you further.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try these right now and let you know what happens! You're a life saver!

Comment: Try using the following code then, to make sure that wordpress will load the CSS file correctly:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`

As for WordPress best practices, it's now recommended to use the following function to load custom/external css.

`wp_enqueue_style ('my-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');`

Both of them should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Based on what you told me, Chris, I think that the issue might be the path to the CSS. When I load the style.css page, it basically opens up a page with all the HTML (no styling or content). Here is a link to a screencap: https://imgur.com/a/lEUZtpt. Thanks again for the help. Might you know where I could go to learn how to adjust the path properly? Leandro, I will try out what you posted right now. Thank you for the help and support!

Comment: The following page gives a bit more info about including CSS and JavaScript to your themes/pages. [https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/)

Comment: Leandro! Thank you! I tried using the first block of code you mentioned and it worked! My goodness I have been working on this for days now and its great to see some progress. Regarding the second block of code, where exactly should I put that? Still in the header? And how should it be bracketed? Are there any tags to preface it with? (Sorry if my jargon is wrong. I mean to ask, should I encase it with <> and should there be any tags before hand i.e. <a href> or something of that nature). Thanks again! And thank you chris!!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help. Regarding that second block of code, it should be included as PHP code, within your header.php file (I think it would work adding it directly on that HTML file too, as long as it's included as PHP code - enclosed by `<?php` and `?>`) - and that should be enough for the style to be loaded. Just as a note, I was the one answering you from the beggining, Chris just edited my answer to make sure the code was properly highlighted.